# Conditionally append non-matching rows to bottom of table and dealing with blanks using VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to create a VBA module in excel that compares two columns of property numbers (master: column A, sheet1, destination: column A, sheet2) and returns all non-matching values from the master (i.e. present in master, but not in destination) to the bottom of the destination table (i.e. first blank row at the end of the destination table). So far I have something that works pretty well, but I discovered a few hiccups when testing.

Code:

```
Sub MergeData()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim recRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim fCell As Range
Dim i As Long

'Define our worksheets
Set wsSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

recRow = 1

With wsSource
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        'See if item is in Master sheet
        Set fCell = wsDest.Range("A:A").Find(what:=.Cells(i, "A").Value, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
            'Record is already in master sheet
            recRow = fCell.Row
        Else
            'Need to move this to master sheet after last found record
            .Cells(i, "A").Cells.Copy
            wsDest.Cells(lastRow, "A").Cells.Insert
            recRow = recRow
        End If
    Next i
```

One issue I noticed was when there are blanks in the destination table things get a little wonky (example):

Before running module:

```
  M|D

  1|1

  2|     

  3|3
```

After:

```
M|D

1|1

2| 

3|2

 |3
```

Notice that the blank cell remains and the order of the returned results is changed. My desired result is:

```
M|D

1|1

2| 

3|3

 |2
```

The desired result preserves the order, as well as the blank (which shouldn't exist in the master data, but I'm preparing for worst case scenarios as I am not the DBA for the master table). Not getting the desired result in this instance is problematic because the destination sheet needs to be "static" (i.e. preserve row order). There will be columns next to column A in the destination sheet where multiple users will be entering comments and if the destination table shifts (beyond adding rows at the end) or re-orders comments will become detached from their original associated property number. Chaos ensues and so on.

I'm very green with VBA so I can't seem to figure out the errors of my ways (there may be more errors, but I have yet to discover anything else when testing so pointing them out would be greatly appreciated). Also, if this information is pertinent, the master list is a SQL connected table that will be periodically refreshed (so the process would be refresh master (dynamic, i.e. order of rows can and does change), run module to return new property numbers to bottom of destination sheet, users add comments and filter destination sheet in excel (static, i.e. order of rows do not change except when all columns are simultaneously filtered or sorted). Thank you all in advance. This community has helped me break through so many roadblocks, hopefully this will be another success story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using something more akin to:

```
dim i as long, dim lrs as long, lrd as long
with sheets(1)
    lrs = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
    for i = 2 to lrs 'assumes header in row 1
        if application.iferror(application.match(.cells(i,1),sheets(2).columns(1),0),0)=0 then
            lrd = sheets(2).cells(sheets(2).rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
            sheets(2).cells(lrd+1,1).value = .cells(i,1).value
        end if
    next i
end with
```

this will allow you to check if the value exists (using match) and if it doesn't match, it will get added to that list, at the bottom, then move to the next line from the source data.

Comment: You could also use application.isna() instead of the iferror to take advatnage of true/false

Comment: Cyril, I'm getting a "Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return and object" error on this line :  lrs = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Row(xlUp).Row" Any thoughts? Again apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Check the edit i made.  sorry, i had put in row(xlup) instead of end(xlup) as i wrote this off the collar, rather than in an IDE

Comment: Cyril, you beautiful genius. It works like a charm. Only thing I needed to change was adding "Dim" in front of that last variable (lrd). Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Cyril, thought I'd follow up with you quickly before posting a separate question because you were incredibly helpful with this response. I'm trying to slot in a line to that last if statement that makes the font color of the "new values" being added to the row in sheet 2 red and I'm having trouble. The idea being that the "new" values would stand out and an autofilter line I have would surface them to the top. I was just going to use conditional formatting, but I think a VBA solution would be cleaner. Thanks again for your help on my first problem.